# In Snowflake how does warehouse provisioning takes place

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

**In Snowflake 2XLarge Warehouse may at times take longer to provision than a XSmall Warehouse.**

Is that possible

Comment: If you've seen this happening, then the answer is "yes, it's possible"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, warehouses are collections of provider resources, so it takes longer to collect bigger computer clusters. Just like it takes longer to start instances in AWS of more complex instance types. I suspect that is due to AWS renting them on the instance auction pool.

I once ran a 4XLarge, and it took just over a minute for the cluster to start working.

There is also a timers for it in the [QUERY_HITSORY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/query_history.html) that measures it, QUEUED_PROVISIONING_TIME